# What is the use of tea servlet framework?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm confused of the usage of `TeaFramework` in java environment. Could you please clarify me by giving clear explanation about it. And if possible please give a sample project about it. I searched in internet but I couldn't find that.

Comment: http://teatrove.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The question is closed but I just stumbled on it a year later and wanted to mention for the record that Disney/ESPN released a much newer version at http://teatrove.org/ and that the SourceForge project is no longer updated. Disclosure: I was involved with the release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The TeaServlet is a framework that sits on top of the Servlet API and
>   creates a separation  between data and presentation. The TeaServlet
>   requires a servlet container to run in.

Quote source: http://teatrove.sourceforge.net/docs/TeaServletTutorial.pdf

The TeaServlet allows dynamic web pages to be created by Tea templates. Tea is a language designed specifically for text formatting, and the TeaServlet uses it to enforce separation between actual web page design and application logic.

Answer (score 3):

Tea is an out of date project, from the very first wave of web frameworks built on top of the Servlet API. The various project pages mentioned in other answers haven't been updated in approximately a dozen years, which is an *eternity* in Internet time.

Ignore it, and use something much more modern instead.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the internet, too, and found the following site, which looks promising:

[Tea Trove on SourceForge.net](http://teatrove.sourceforge.net/teaservlet.html)

Also take a look at this pdf document, it contains the creation of a sample application and more:

[TeaServlet Tutorial](http://teatrove.sourceforge.net/docs/TeaServletTutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

> The [TeaServlet](http://teatrove.sourceforge.net/teaservlet.html) is a template engine that works with the Tea template language. The TeaServlet makes it easy for developers to create web applications that separate the data acquisition from the presentation.

So inorder to avoid [Problems with Jsp](http://www.servlets.com/soapbox/problems-jsp.html) Tea has been introduced.

- Seems that Tea and JSP are very similar.
- Both have the goal of separating presentation from business logic.

Then??

```
 What are the advantages/disadvantages of `Tea` vs. JSP?
```

Some of the differences are outlined in the documentation on the Tea language.

- Tea is simpler than JSP
- easier to customize (functions are easier to write than taglibs)
- and it enforces separation. JSP can only encourage it.

As @Sean Reilly said,its **WORTHLESS**.